# Charclass/Interchartokes for Umlauts and „“

Tags: xetex, characters, kerning

How can I define a charclass for umlauts, german quotes `„“` (and other special characters which are not A–Z/a–z)?
I’d like to use this for extra kerning in some cases.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1

% char class for W
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassW
\XeTeXcharclass `\W \mycharclassW
% char class for german ä (a umlaut)
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassae
\XeTeXcharclass `a \mycharclassae
% char class for german opening quote „
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassOQ
% charclass for german closing quote “
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassCQ

% def interchartokes
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassW \mycharclassae = {\kern0.5pt}

\begin{document}
Wa\quad Wä\quad „W“
\end{document}
```

How can I add more than one char to a new class, e.g., making C, O, U and Q available in one class (`\mycharclassCOQU`)?

Comment: @xport: I'd keep XeTeX in the title.

Comment: @egreg: I think it is unnecessary because we already have tag system.

Comment: @xport: Thanks for correcting :-). I thought it would be better to have “XeTeX” in title, cause it is more visible than a tag. but you’re right it is redundant so I’d agree with you, removing it from title …

Comment: several months ago, other users also edited my title when I put unnecessary words as you did above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the same way:

```
\XeTeXcharclass `ä \mycharclassae
```

You should naturally load fontspec so that the char is printed. And the file should be in utf8.

Comment: That works fine. Thanks! ps. what’s the difference between using `W` and `\W` after the `

Answer (score 5):

```
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassCOQU
\XeTeXcharclass `\C \mycharclassCOQU
\XeTeXcharclass `\O \mycharclassCOQU
\XeTeXcharclass `\Q \mycharclassCOQU
\XeTeXcharclass `\U \mycharclassCOQU
```

You can assign as many characters as you want to any class; however, a character may belong to only one class (the last specification wins).

Comment: Thank you! (Unfortunately it isn’t possible to vote two answers as “accepted“ so I voted Ulrike’s answer because it is the one which answers the question in the title.But I voted both as “useful”)